# Filter CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I set CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies to true and want to filter the output. So I used the following code:

```
  <Target Name="FilterCopyLocalItems" AfterTargets="ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But this code did not work, how can I put a filter on the output?

Comment: It seems that you use a net core project and add these node in it to remove the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` from the `bin` output folder. So I just wonder what did you mean by `this code did not work`?

Comment: The target "ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "..\build\zip.props (2,40)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target `FilterCopyLocalItems` is to remove the reference dll from the output folder.

I wonder if you means that the target cannot be executed.

For me, I used the below xml code in my net core project which installed the nuget package [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Target Name="FilterCopyLocalItems" AfterTargets="ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
    
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can find the target under the **Detailed** output build log.

Enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to **Detailed**.

And you can see the target by searching its name under the detailed output log while you build it.

It will prevent the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` being generated in the output folder.

**Update 1**

**Actually**, you may do some extra operation which causes the target `ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps` not to be triggered. Due to the lack of your detailed project structure and CSPROJ file, I did not notice that.

For your situation, the target `ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild` works well.

So in your side, you should use this:

```
<Target Name="FilterCopyLocalItems" AfterTargets="ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
          <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'" />
        </ItemGroup>
      </Target>
```

**Besides**, when you execute the target, please do not add  `<ExcludeAssets>Runtime</ExcludeAssets>` under the PackageReference of your nuget package, its effect is actually the role of your target `FilterCopyLocalItems`. At runtime, remove the related `package.dll` in the output folder. [See this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

So you should delete it to avoid reuse.

Comment: Thank you very much, Yes, you got it right, I'm not going to copy some assemblies to the output folder. For this purpose, I used ResolveLockFileCopyLocalProjectDeps to filter them but it did not work and instead, I used ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild which worked fine.
However, I do not intend to include the loading path of these assemblies in the "Project.deps" file. I designed a modular system, and the purpose of this request is to load some assemblies from the DefaultAssemblyLoadContext.
I create an issue for this in https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/19448

Comment: Sorry for not obtaining your project's structure and `csproj` file, so I did not notice it. And thanks for sharing this important info with us.  Also, please delete `<ExcludeAssets>Runtime</ExcludeAssets>` and its effect is the same as your target `FilterCopyLocalItems`.

Comment: I have updated my answer and since we discussed the issue about executing the target rather than the modular system. So I suggest you could mark this answer and then open a new ticket about your issue of modular system on SO.:)